# tooltip to dynamic position to show the data in the table

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a table with data and when i mouse over on one of the column in the table, it has to show the tooltip at top right position, issue is for the first row in the table the tooltip data is getting hidden as table header has to show up. How to resolve it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class name to the first and second rows and for those rows only adjust the popup to desired position:

```
.firstRow a.tooltip:hover span, 
.secondRow a.tooltip:hover span {
    bottom:auto;
    top:10px
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WH7WV/1/)

if you cannot add class names to your rows, then use css nth-child:

```
.GridviewScrollItem:nth-child(3) a.tooltip:hover span, 
.GridviewScrollItem:nth-child(2) a.tooltip:hover span {
    bottom:auto;
    top:10px
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WH7WV/3/)

Comment: Thanks Sammy, but iam generating the table dynamically in jsp page. so icannot add the class names for first two rows i believe. Please see my jsp code in above post.

Comment: you can use nth-child (css only solution). I updated my answer